# problems intall pil 10.9 mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

```
LocalBeatriz:~ beatrizsuchbeteta$ python install pillow
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
LocalBeatriz:~ beatrizsuchbeteta$ sudo python setup.py install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Hello i need to install pil in python 2.7 for a university homework of informatic but i have a mac and its have been very difficult. i dont know a lot of informatic so dont know what more do, the error is what i pasted. Hope someone can help me, thanks.

mac 10.9.1 mavericks

Answer (score 0):

you'd better try install it with pip.

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

that should work.
If you do not have pip on your mac, you could install pip with

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Answer (score -1):

If you will be doing a lot of homework in Python on a Mac, you should install Canopy. 
It contains most of the modules that you will need, and has a pretty nifty editor. 
Everything that it installs is also accessible from the command line.

https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/